abi.decode throwing error, panic: out of memory
solidity types data structure is like this:
enum RequestType {
        SpecificReq,
        ArbitraryReq
    }

    enum ChannelType {
        InterestBearingOpen,
        InterestBearingMutual,
    }

    struct ChannelPayload {
        string channelAddress;
        ChannelType channelType;
    }

    struct SpecificRequestPayload {
        bytes4 functionSig;
        ChannelPayload channelData;
    }

    struct ArbitraryRequestPayload {
        bytes4 functionSig;
    }

this is how I'm encoding and decoding
    function encodeSpecificReqPayload (SpecificRequestPayload memory _payload) public view returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encode(_payload, msg.sender, RequestType.SpecificReq);
    }

    function encodeArbitraryReqPayload (ArbitraryRequestPayload memory _payload) public view returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encode(_payload, msg.sender, RequestType.ArbitraryReq);
    }

    function decodePayload (bytes memory _payload) public pure returns (uint8 requestType) {
        (,, requestType) = abi.decode(_payload, (bytes, address, uint8));

        if (requestType == 0) {
            // Specific Req Type
            (SpecificRequestPayload memory reqPayload, address sender,) =
                abi.decode(_payload, (SpecificRequestPayload, address, uint8));

            // ROUTE to SPECIFIC REQUEST ROUTING Function
        } else {
            // Arbitrary Req Type
            (ArbitraryRequestPayload memory reqPayload, address sender,) =
                abi.decode(_payload, (ArbitraryRequestPayload, address, uint8));

            // Directly call ARBITRARY REQUEST FUNCTION
        }
    }

It's throwing panic: out of memory exception at abi.decode line when payload is generate from one of the encode functions and sent into decodePayload function
how to resolve this?
PS: it's a cross-chain messaging transfer, and due to this only a single payload can be sent in a tx

Update: Got the solution
The struct payload parameter must be encoded first and then encoded along with other values.
function encodeSpecificReqPayload (SpecificRequestPayload memory _payload) public view returns (bytes memory) {
    bytes memory reqPayloadBytes = abi.encode(_payload);
    return abi.encode(reqPayloadBytes, msg.sender, RequestType.SpecificReq);
}

function encodeArbitraryReqPayload (ArbitraryRequestPayload memory _payload) public view returns (bytes memory) {
    bytes memory reqPayloadBytes = abi.encode(_payload);
    return abi.encode(reqPayloadBytes, msg.sender, RequestType.ArbitraryReq);
}

function decodePayload (bytes memory _payload) public pure {
    (bytes memory payloadS, address sender ,uint8 requestType) = abi.decode(_payload, (bytes, address, uint8));

    if (requestType == 0) {
        // Specific Req Type
        (SpecificRequestPayload memory reqPayload) =
            abi.decode(payloadS, (SpecificRequestPayload));

        // ROUTE to SPECIFIC REQUEST ROUTING Function
    } else {
        // Arbitrary Req Type
        (ArbitraryRequestPayload memory reqPayload) =
            abi.decode(payloadS, (ArbitraryRequestPayload));

        // Directly call ARBITRARY REQUEST FUNCTION
    }
}

